# Can this code have race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
    public static void deleteLast(Vector list) {
    int lastIndex = list.size() - 1;//line 2
    list.remove(lastIndex);         // line 3
}
```

I known Vector is threadsafe in java 
but can this case happen

let's say in this case has list.size()=10

Thread A calls deleteLast and at line 2 lastIndex  = 9 .It stops for some reason

Thread B call deleteLast and at line 2 lastIndex  = 9.it goes to line 3 and now list has 9 elements

Thread A  now wakes up and goes to line 3 now it tries to remove object at index 9  which doesn't exist  and we have an exception  here

Comment: yes!!  as so many collections are ThreadSafe but you need extra thread safety in your code for some instances

Comment: FYI, "Race condition" is not the same as "concurrency defect".  Your example has a defect which you have correctly identified.  "Race condition" usually means the outcome depends on which thread executed a particular statement first.  A race condition is not a defect _unless_ one of the possible outcomes is "wrong" (e.g., `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`).  Your example throws that exception, but I would say it's more complicated than a mere race condition because the problem case is a particular _interleaving_ of several statements, not just a question of which thread gets to line 3 first.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You've correctly identified a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. And you should use a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) rather than a `List` to avoid this scenario.